# Generating every possible position In Tick Tack Toe

Tags: javascript, generator

I want to generate every singe way a tick tack toe board can look. The data format i would like is a simple array that looks kind of like this: 
["", "X", "O",
 "", "X", "X",
 "", "O", "O"]

I need to know witch ones are empty too. I have no idea how to do this. Should iterate over each one and then iterate over every one behind...

Lets say I'm at the third one. Should i then go back to number two and do one for it's every possible state and inside that go to number one?

Is a recursive function what i need?

btw this is actually a screenshot of made with JavaScript. I do have some code.

[image: The board]

Comment: Hint, on every click, try 4 possible combinations, that is horizontal, vertical, left diagonal and right diagonal...

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, show us your code and explain what's wrong with it

Comment: Second Hint: start trying at least to create a file with the HTML grid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you could consider to use only the numbers

- 0 for empty places,
- 1 for user which goes first
- 2 for user which goes second

The whole space of the board is nine fields, which can have in maximum all places filled with player 2.

The numerical value of this is 222222222<sub>3</sub> = 19682<sub>10</sub>.

From this value you have to skip the state of board like the last one, which is not possible, because it misses the player 1 and it have to much places with player 2 on it.

To check which (end) position is valid, you need a check for containing same count of pieces for player 1 and 2 +/- 1,

```js
var value = parseInt('222222222', 3);

console.log(value);
```

To get all positions, you could iterate form zero to the 19682, convert the number to a string with `radix = 3` and pad the string with zero to the lenght of 9.

Then check the board and eliminate impossible states.

```js
function pad9(v) { return ('000000000' + v).slice(-9); }
var max = parseInt('222222222', 3), 
    i,
    output = '';

for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    // add some checks brefore output
    output += pad9(i.toString(3)) + '\n';
}
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```